# coinbase pro api size is too accurate. Smallest unit is 0.10000000

Tags: node.js, typescript, coinbase-api

I am using below coinbase pro api to make a sell request

```
const sellParams = {"side":"sell","product_id":"DOGE-USD","type":"market","size":"135.5200"}
try{
                    sellResp  = await authedClient.placeOrder(sellParams)
                    functions.logger.log("Sold today at:", sellResp)
                 }catch(err)
```

how it fails with error like below, I don't get this as my unit is bigger than that.

```
Failed with error: { Error: HTTP 400 Error: size is too accurate. Smallest unit is 0.10000000
    at Request._callback (/workspace/node_modules/coinbase-pro/lib/clients/public.js:68:15)
    at Request.self.callback (/workspace/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:466:23)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/request/request.js:1154:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:466:23)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/request/request.js:1076:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
```

Comment: 0.02 looks to be smaller than 0.1.

Comment: Yep, the error is telling you you can do 135.5, or 135.6, but not 135.52

Answer (score 0):

Coinbase and many other exchanges have a standard increment for quantity usually varying by market. In this case, your size must be in increments of 0.1. **135.5** or **135.6** would be acceptable order sizes.

Most exchanges have an api call to get all of the market information including minimum order sizes, increments, etc. It is usually best to get this when you start your application. For coinbase -> https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#products

Might I also suggest using the [CCXT library](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt) as it abstracts much of this detail for you.